# Is it possible to return an array from Java to C++ through a return value of a method?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, java-native-interface, return

I know that one can pass an array from Java to C++ by native methods, but in that case you have to run the Java code.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
public float[] testing2(float[] value1, int[] value2);
```

Is there a way to address the return-type `float[]` from the C++ code? And in case it's not, what's the easiest way to do it and is it possible without having to run the code from Java?

EDIT TO DUPLICATE:

The possible duplicate isn't a duplicate since I'm asking for another way than native methods to access this `float[]` - but in the other questions native methods are used.

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to call a method with a return type of `float[]` that was written in Java using C++ code. Correct?

Comment: Exactly. I want to call a method with a return type of `float[]` that was written in Java out of a C++ environment. If that's not possible, then what is the best way to access this `float[]`?

Comment: What do you mean by " native"  methods? The normal interpretation of that is "not in the JVM", i.e. all your C++ methods are native methods.  And I don't see either how you can return an array from Java code without running Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `CallObjectMethod()`.

Precondition: Assume in C++ you have

- `JNIEnv* env;`
- A global or local reference `obj` which has the Java method `public float[] testing2(float[] value1, int[] value2)` as you described
- `val1` which is a reference to Java `float[]`
- `val2` which is a reference to Java `int[]`.

Then,

```
jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jmethodID testing2meth = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "testing2", "([F[I)[F");
jfloatArray ret = (jfloatArray)env->CallObjectMethod(obj, testing2meth, val1, val2);
```

Then you can use `GetFloatArrayElements()` or `GetFloatArrayRegion()` to access `ret`.

Comment: sorry for the late answer - but could you specify what you mean by `obj`'? Cause I'm traying your solution but getting some runtime-errors when calling `(jfloatArray)env->CallObjectMethod(obj, testing2meth, val1, val2);`

Comment: @yiiit1 `obj` refers to a Java object which has method `testing2()`. Show your code. How did you obtain `obj`?

Comment: I managed, had to use `CallStaticObjectMethod` - thanks for your help, that was exactly the solution I was searching for!

Comment: @yiiit1 Really? But in your question you didn't declare `testing2()` as `static`...

Comment: it's a problem i have all the time, it also happens for the other two methods i have - doesn't matter if the method is static or not, i always have to take the static-version.. i have no idea..